# why controls in winform can change name dynamicly?

Tags: c#, winforms

As we know,we can rename controls in winform by changing it's property,such as btn_Run.But the code in Form.Designer.cs was also changed( private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1; ->  private System.Windows.Forms.Button btn_Run;).

How can it do dynamically?I mean,how can it band control.name with new Object?

Comment: When you rename a control in the form designer, the form designer generates code with the new name. That's not dynamic anything; it's design time code generation. If you assign a new string to `button1.Name` at runtime, the name of the field in your form class will not change to match.

Comment: If you're asking why the binding doesn't break if you change the name at run-time, it's because binding happens when the form loads (for controls created in the designer) - after that it's a binary reference that doesn't refer to the name anymore.

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what you are asking, whether you are inquiring about how this happens in Visual Studio - which this is simply a function of the Visual Studio IDE. The `designer.cs` file is auto-generated based on what you change in the visual designer. - Or, are you asking how you can do that during run-time?

Comment: I wanna to know if there is possible to declare a variable which specify by local data.For example,Person Jim = new Person();Person Mary = new Person(): Jim and Mary both loaded from database.

Comment: @Vincent That's a separate question, but you're approaching it in the wrong way. I suggest you research how to retrieve records from a database using ADO.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. A WinForms control that you add through the designer gets a field declared. When you rename it through the designer, the designer renames the field. You cannot change field names at runtime.

You can however change *control names* at runtime. Each control has a [`string Name { get; set; }` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.name?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Name).

So you can do:

```
button1.Name = "MyNewName";
```

You can then do:

```
var foundButton = this.Controls.Find("MyNewName", true).FirstOrDefault();
```